# padding destroying div into a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hi i am trying to put a div into a div
but the second one is going to have padding on the left and the right.

what i have as a result is a blue div which is pushing out of the black bordered div 'page'

fiddle show it a little bit on the right. A web page show it with as much as 50px So it should be y padding left, right which are 25 each, but i dont jnow where the mistake come from in
 the code
http://jsfiddle.net/124a0yd9/

Thanks to all

CSS:

```
.page{
border:solid 4px black;
width:100%;
}

.slogan_c {
    color: #0099cc;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
        font-size:8px;
margin-top:40px;
margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 100%
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
border:solid 1px red;

}



.slogan_f{
border:solid 1px pink;
        color: #ffffff;
    background-color: blue;
font-weight: bold;
        font-size:30px;
margin-top:40px;
margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 100%;
padding-left:35px;
padding-right:35px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='page'>

<DIV class='slogan_f'>
Texte 1, Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,
</DIV>
<BR><BR><BR>
<DIV class='slogan_c'>
TExte 2, TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,
</DIV>

</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to deduct the total width with the padding (left + right) - border size to achieve 100% width.

```
.slogan_f{ 
  width: calc(100% - 72px);
}
```

Total div Width (100%) - padding-left (35px) - padding-right (35px) - border-left (1px) - border-right (1px)

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/124a0yd9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change for ***.slogan_f***

```
.slogan_f {
width :auto}
```

---

***Code:***

```css
.page {
  border: solid 4px black;
  width: 100%;
}
.slogan_c {
  color: #0099cc;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100% padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.slogan_f {
  border: solid 1px pink;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>

  <DIV class='slogan_f'>
    Texte 1, Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,Texte 1,
  </DIV>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <DIV class='slogan_c'>
    TExte 2, TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,TExte 2,
  </DIV>

</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because padding accumulates with your width:

So you will have a width of 100% + (35px *2)... Resulting in a div wider than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you got 70px padding in your div + 100% width and you need to delete the border or change it to 0.
    border:solid 0px pink;

Answer (score 0):

div this to the inner `div`: `box-sizing: border-box;` and you can give the width of the inner one to 100% with any padding you want.